# How Restful Request Public Key and Private Key Works for each request

Tags: php, jquery, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am looking at public key and private key encryption for web request. I came across some API which encrypts data using jQuery with public key which is requested from server and then passed to server for further process.

My question is how to handle such dynamically created public/private key each time. Say for example we are requesting RSA public key from server and encrypt data and pass to server, how server will know which key pair will be used for that request.

I am seeing some examples like http://www.jcryption.org/ in that it requests key and passed to server for decryption, say I have plenty of requests that generate separate key for each request how we can decode on server side.

Comment: “some API”? Care to tell us what it is?

Comment: Well I am trying to build restful services, with some encryption, just new to this. so wanted to know the mechanism

Comment: For now I have found two encryption: jcryption and pidCrypt which may requires pem file that I dont have too